# datadog local check setup same as check_mk local check for monitoring

Tags: monitoring, nagios, datadog, check-mk, datadog-dashboard

I would like to setup datadog local check ( same as check_mk local check )
https://docs.checkmk.com/latest/en/localchecks.html
As example when i echo out the result in shell script as parameter fist parameter get as ,ok ,warm ,critical in check_mk , then 2nd parameter get as service name ,..etc
How can I create same monitor in datadog , I have search all over the documentation and could not find such method , any similar methods available in datadog ?

after creating shell script output parameter integrate to the datadog for monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to the community!

I am no expert on the matter, but as far as I know, it is possible.
Here are some references:

- https://pypi.org/project/datadog-checks-base/
- https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/blob/main/docs/dev/checks/README.md
- https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/write_agent_check/?tab=agentv6v7